# grep: Ignoring GREP_OPTIONS to search case-sensitive

Tags: grep, environment-variables, case-sensitivity

I have set `GREP_OPTIONS="--ignore-case --color"` in `~/.bashrc` as I normally want grep to work case-insensitive. However, there are times when I need grep to actually search case-sensitive, but the man page doesn´t suggest a param for this.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I probably would define an alias with my options, e.g.:

```
alias grep="grep --ignore-case --color"
```

as this would only affect interactive programs and not scripts. You could then just run `\grep` or `/bin/grep` to run it without any options.

If you want to keep using `GREP_OPTIONS` you can just unset it for your commandline, e.g.

```
GREP_OPTIONS= grep ....
```

Comment: +1 didn't know about the `\command-name` is used to refer to the original command and not the alias. Really helpful.

Comment: possibly relevant: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/35789/4098

Comment: @mtk see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39291/run-a-command-that-is-shadowed-by-an-alias for other methods

Comment: "command grep"  : will launch the grep command (ie, the one found in the $PATH) even if there is an alias or functino with the same name. Usefull to prepend a "command" to actual command's use in alias and function definitions (and elsewhere when you want to bypass any eventual alias or function definition of the same cmd)